# No me funcionan mis evento addeventlistener

Tags: javascript

Lo que hago es cargar por `onload` dos funciones y después ejecutar con `click` otras funciones más, pero no funcionan.

Código:

```
window.onload = index


function index(){
datos_datos_usuario()
cargar_informacion_usuario()
document.getElementById('boton_info').addEventListener("click",publicar)
document.getElementById('boton_cancelar').addEventListener("click",ocultar_contenedores)
document.getElementById('boton_aceptar').addEventListener("click",categoria)
document.getElementById('opciones_c').addEventListener("click",elegir)
}
```

Código html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Fabrica</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/estilosl.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="../JS/funciones.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body >
<div id="cabecera">
    <div id="etiqueta_casa">
        <img id="casa" src="../Imagenes/casa.svg">
    </div>
    <input id="buscador" type="text" placeholder="Buscar...">
    <img id="usuario_img" src="../Imagenes/user.svg">
    <p id="nombre_ud"></p>
</div>
<div id="informacion_usuario">
    <div id="publicar">
        <textarea id="atexto" placeholder="Reseña"></textarea>
        <button id="boton_p">Publicar</button>
        <div id="opciones_c" >
            Categorias

        </div>

    </div>


</div>
<div id="fondo_borroso"></div>
<div id="opciones_categorias">
    <h1>Elige una opcion</h1>
    <input class="opcion" type="radio" name="elegir" value="Electronicos">Electronicos<br>
    <input class="opcion" type="radio" name="elegir" value="Animales">Animales<br>
    <input class="opcion" type="radio" name="elegir" value="Pantallas">Pantallas<br>
    <input class="opcion" type="radio" name="elegir" value="Consolas">Consolas<br>
    <input class="opcion" type="radio" name="elegir" value="Ropa">Ropa<br>
    <input class="opcion" type="radio" name="elegir" value="Pintura">Pintura<br>
    <button id="boton_cancelar" class="boton_e">Cancelar</button>
    <button id="boton_aceptar" class="boton_e">Aceptar</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Se supone que `datos_usuarios()` carga el nombre del usuario y `cargar_informacion_usuario()` carga sus reseñas o publicaciones.

Por lo que antes de cargar la página deberían estar ahi plasmados los datos. Pero no me funcionan los botones al querer hacer click. Estos despliegan un menu.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando se publica una reseña se coloca en el contenedor de reseñas(color café). Pero al querer publicar otra no me sirve el boton "publicar reseña"(color azul), ni el de "desplegar menu"(color rosa).

Comment: Podrias agregar el codigo html que tienes para poderte ayudar mejor

Comment: Si colocas: 1.- El resultado que obtienes al momento, tu HTML completo y describes mejor lo que buscas lograr, seguro alguien te ayuda

Comment: Creo que podrias aumentar mas detalles sobre el error que se genera, ya nos vamos haciendo una idea mejor del problema

Comment: Buenas, en ocasiones me ha pasado esto.. Y es porque los elementos HTML aún no se habían creado... Es cierto que lo haces en el onload, pero te recomiendo que pruebes colocando el script al final del body (antes de la etiqueta </body>). Saludos!

Comment: @Jorge ¿Puedes confirmar que las funciones se llaman igual? Es que en un lado has puesto `datos_datos_usuario()` y en otro `datos_usuario()`